# Safe to iterate values collection of hasmap after key removal?

Tags: java

```
    HashMap<String, DBrow> datamap = new HashMap<String, DBrow>();
    datamap.remove(key);

    Collection<DBrow> values = datamap.values();

    for(DBrow dbrow : values){
        //is key's value removed from hashmap?
        //ignore case where another key may have the same reference.
    }
```

I'm not sure if the hashmap just relies on the garbage collector to eventually delete the value mapped from key, or if it's instantly removed?  I don't see a way to guarantee removal of the k/v pair in a hashmap, just the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys and values in a map are linked together. A `Map` is "nothing else" than a `Set` of [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) objects. (see [`.entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29)). Removing a key in fact removes the whole entry.

The `.keySet()` and `.values()` method just construct ad-hoc `Set`s and `Collection`s from these entries.

Note that if this were not the case, you could not be able to guarantee that the iteration order of keys were the same as the iteration order of values. This would be annoying, wouldn't it? ;)

Comment: I got spooked after reading about weakhashmaps, where it decides to get rid of the value when the key is no longer in existence.  I got worried normal hasmaps may just wait for the gc as well.  

I see that's that's just a fall back position for weakhashmaps; for any type of hashmap apparently when u delete the key directly in map, its value is instantly deleted as well  Your entry set explanation helped me understand this -- how they are paired and that deletion is immediate, so that's why I chose this answer.

Comment: Note what the doc of `WeakHashMap` says: "An **entry** in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key is no longer in ordinary use." (emphasis mine)

Comment: A weakhashmap relies on the gc for "not in ordinary use" detection which isn't instant.  If you remove the key from the weakhasmap or hashmap i now see that in either case removal of the value is instant via that method.

Comment: To be honest, I don't have the slightest experience with weak references... I know there are weak, soft and strong references with strong being the default but that's about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Hashmap.remove(key)` removes the mapping for the key and returns the mapped value or `null` if there was no mapping.  If you don't hold any other references to the value, it willl be garbage collected. So, no other action is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Java doc for the remove method says:

```
   //Removes the mapping for the specified key from this map if present.
public V remove(Object key) {....
```

So removing the key also ensures removing the value associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Value will be removed instantly, an entry inside `hashmap` is nothing but an object of `Entry` Class which has `Key` and `Value` fields. when you call remove on map it will find the object based on the `hash code` value and checks for `equality` if true it will remove the entire object reference.